# Hypothesis Testing under uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

A recent article in Healthy Life magazine claimed that the mean amount of leisure time per week for European men is $48.5$ hours. The distribution of leisure time amounts is reported to be approximately Normal. You believe the figure of 48.5 is too large and decide to conduct your own test. In a random sample of 25 European men, you find that the mean is $45$ hours of leisure per week and that the standard deviation of the sample is $7.8$ hours.

(a) Conduct the test and determine the $p$‒value. At $\alpha=0.01$ significance level, can you conclude that the information in the article is untrue?

$$\begin{cases}
&H_{0}: &\mu>=48.5\\
&H_{1}: &\mu<48.5
\end{cases}$$

The $t$-statistic yields:

$$t\text{-stat} =\frac{45-48.5}{7.8/5}=-3.5/1.56\approx -2.244$$

$0.025<p\text{-value}<0.01$

so that

$p-\text{value}>\alpha$ implies that we do not reject $H_0$

(b) How would your answer to part (a) be affected if the distribution of leisure time amounts was uniform?

Especially, I wonder the question (b).

Comment: Isn't it $7.8$ and not $7.5$ in the denominator?
Moreover, even if it is $7.8$, in both cases, your one-tail test has a $p$-value between $0.025$ and $0.01$, so that you do not reject $H_{0}$.

Comment: I updated my comment. Mind that $0.025>p\text{-value}>0.01$

Comment: It can't be: $0.025>0.01$. You have $t_{24;0.975}\approx 2.064$ and $t_{24;0.99}\approx2.492$, so that your $p$-value is between $0.01$ and $0.025$. Since $0.025>0.01$, you also have $0.025>p\text{-value}>0.01$.

Comment: I understand thanks!

Comment: For your second problem, I do not have the time to think about it right now but I will take a look later if nobody does.

Comment: Shouldn't $H_1$ be $\mu<48.5$?

Comment: Yes H0 >= 48.5, H1 < 48.5 is right i think